# What could cause a meteor app to sometimes create two documents?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a meteor app that takes the text of an article and splits it into paragraphs, sentences, words, and characters and then stores that in a json which I then save as a document in a collection. The document I am testing now ends up as 15133 bytes in mongodb.

When I insert the document it takes about 20 or 30 seconds to insert. Then sometimes it starts going through my article creation routine again and inserts another document. Sometimes it ends up inserting 3 or more documents. Sometimes it behaves as it should and only inserts 1 document into the collection.

What should I be looking for that could be causing this behavior?

Here is my code, as requested:

```
Meteor.methods({
'createArticle': function (text, title) {
    var article = {}
    article.title = title
    article.userID = "sdfgsdfg"
    article.text = text
    article.paragraphs = []
    var paragraphs = splitArticleIntoParagraphs(text)
    console.log("paragraphs", paragraphs)
    _.each(paragraphs, function (paragraph, p) {
        if (paragraph !== "") {
            console.log("paragraph", paragraph)
            article.paragraphs[p] = {}
            article.paragraphs[p].read = false
            article.paragraphs[p].text = paragraph
            console.log("paragraphs[p]", article.paragraphs[p])
            var sentences = splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph)
            article.paragraphs[p].sentences = []
        }
        _.each(sentences, function (sentence, s) {
            if (sentence !== "") {
                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s] = {}
                console.log("sentence", sentence)
                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].text = sentence
                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].read = false
                console.log("paragraphs[p].sentences[s]", article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s])
                var wordsForward = splitSentenceIntoWordsForward(sentence)
                console.log("wordsForward", JSON.stringify(wordsForward))
                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward = {}
                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words = wordsForward

                // var wordsReverse = splitSentenceIntoWordsReverse(sentence)
                _.each(wordsForward, function (word, w) {
                    if (word) {
                        // console.log("word", JSON.stringify(word))
                        // article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s] = {}
                        // article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward = {}
                        // article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words = []
                        article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w] = {}
                        article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].wordID = word._id
                        article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].simp = word.simp
                        article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].trad = word.trad
                        console.log("word.simp", word.simp)
                        var characters = word.simp.split('')
                        console.log("characters", characters)
                        article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters = []
                        _.each(characters, function (character, c) {
                            if (character) {
                                console.log("character", character, p, s, w, c)
                                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters[c] = {}
                                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters[c].text = character
                                article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters[c].wordID = Words.findOne({simp: character})._id
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
    // console.log("article", JSON.stringify(article))
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(article.paragraphs[10].sentences[1].forward))//.words[4].characters[0])
    console.log("done")
    var id = Articles.insert(article)
    console.log("id", id)
    return id
}
})
```

I call the method here:

```
Template.articleList.events({
"click #addArticle": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var text = $('#text').val();
    $('#title').value = '';
    $('#text').value = '';
    $('#text').attr('rows', '3');
    Meteor.call('createArticle', text, title);
 }
})
```

Comment: please edit your question and add your related codes.

Comment: can you check if it waits _.each() (all of them) before inserting the article? Thats probably the culprit here. Also, please add where you call the method just in case

Comment: Added the method call. So, are you saying that I should insert the article and then update it as it goes through the _.each? It takes about 20 to 30 seconds after `console.log("done")`

Comment: no, I was saying that you should check if it inserts right away or after the splitting is done. I'd probably split on the client side by the way

Comment: It inserts after the splitting is done.

Comment: try returning error/result in your call and lets see how many times it is called each time. do you know how you can do this?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126562/discussion-between-luna-and-webmagnets).

Comment: I did this ```Meteor.call('createArticle', text, title, function(err, result){
            if(!err) {
                console.log("result",result)
            } else {
                console.log("err", err)
            }
        })``` and it neither prints an error or the result. Also, "clicked" only prints once no matter how many times the document is inserted.

Comment: I take that back. It does print the result. And it prints it only once no matter how many times the document is inserted.

Comment: It may not be your case here, but remember that if the client does not receive the result (or error) from the server (e.g. due to bad connectivity), it will retry the `Meteor.call` on next connection. This may end up calling several times your method, if the server _did_ receive the previous calls.

Comment: @webmagnets Okay. Then the easiest solution would be moving the split codes to the client side and sending the data ready to insert to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important thing to keep in mind is that meteor methods do not work very well when it comes to perform CPU intensive tasks. Since your meteor server only works in a single thread, any kind of blocking computations - like yours - will affect all client connections, e.g. delaying DDP heartbeats. This - in turn - can result in clients thinking that the connection was dropped.

As @ghybs suggested in one of the comments your method is probably triggered several times by an impatient DDP client who thinks that server has disconnected. The easiest way to prevent this behavior is by adding `noRetry` flag to `Meteor.apply` as explained here:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-apply

I believe `Meteor.call` does not have this option.

Another strategy would be trying to make sure that your methods are idempotent, i.e. calling them more than once should not produce any additional effects. This is usually true - at least when you use method simulation - because retrying db insert will re-use the same document `id` which will fail on the second try. For some reason this is not happening in your case.

Finally, the problem you described clearly shows that probably a different pattern should be used for a computationally expensive task like yours. If I were you, I would start by splitting the job in several steps:

1. First I would make sure that the document is uploaded to the server with a POST request rather than through DDP.
2. Then I would implement a "process file" server side method that grabs the file which is already on the server or in the database (in case you used files collection). The first thing the method should do would be calling `this.unblock()`, but thats not all.
3. Ideally the computational task should be executed in a separated process. Only when that process is completed the method would return telling the actual caller that the job is done. But since we called `this.unblock()` that caller can perform different tasks, e.g. calling other methods/subscriptions while waiting for the result.

Sometimes, having a separated process will not be good enough. I've experienced situations where I had to delegate the task to another worker server(s).

Comment: Doing it on the client side works. Also, the reason it was taking 20+ seconds to insert was because I was validating the data with the  SimpleSchema package. I stopped doing that and the insertion time was almost instantaneous.